# how can solve the error canvas and GameWidget

Tags: python, kivy

after I write a code to build a game. I got this errors. How can I fix them? I really confuse about it.
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:/PycharmProjects/Hello worl/venv/kivy#2.py", line 6, in 
     class GameWidget(Widget):
   File "D:/PycharmProjects/Hello worl/venv/kivy#2.py", line 12, in GameWidget
     with self.canvas:
 NameError: name 'self' is not defined

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.core.window import Window


class GameWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._on_keyboard_close, 
self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_key_down)

        with self.canvas:
           self.player = Rectangle(source="hero.bmp", pos=(0, 0), size=(100, 
100))

    def _on_keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_key_down)
        self._keyboard = none

    def _on_key_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        currentx = self.player.pos[0]
        currenty = self.player.pos[1]
        newx = currentx
        newy = currenty

        if text == "w":
            currenty += 1
        if text == "s":
            currenty -= 1
        if text == "a":
            currentx -= 1
        if text == "d":
            currentx += 1

        self.player.pos = (currentx, currenty)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GameWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.run()
```

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect.

Comment: Hello John
Thank You. May I ask you to explain more? because I am new at kivy. Is it possible to tell me how can I correct my indentation?

Comment: Your indentation is fine after your edit.

Comment: But Now. I got this errors! Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:/PycharmProjects/Hello worl/venv/kivy#2.py", line 44, in <module>
     app.run()
   File "D:\Tools\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 829, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "D:/PycharmProjects/Hello worl/venv/kivy#2.py", line 39, in build
     return GameWidget()
   ", line 10, in __init__
     self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._on_keyboard_close, self)
 AttributeError: 'GameWidget' object has no attribute '_on_keyboard_close'

Comment: That's because you spell it as `_on_keyboard_close` in one place, and `_on_keyboard_closed` in another.